# $f: [a. b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, then $g(x) = \inf\{f(s) \mid x< s\}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f: [a. b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then $g(x) = \inf\{f(s) \mid  x< s\}$ is continuous and non-decreasing.

My attempt:

Of course $g$ is non-decreasing: if $x_1 \leq x_2$, we should show that $g(x_1) \leq g(x_2)$. It is obvious, because $\{s \mid  x_2 < s\} \subset \{s \mid  x_1 < s\}$.

Now, we want to prove that $g$ is continuous. So, we will prove that $g$ is continuous in every $x_0 \in [a, b]$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we should find $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x, x_0) < \delta \implies d\big(g(x), g(x_0)\big) < \epsilon$.

As $f$ is continuous, $f$ is continuous in $x_0$. Then, there is $\delta_f > 0$ such that $d(x, x_0) < \delta_f \implies d\big(f(x), f(x_0)\big) < \epsilon$, that is, if $x \in \big(x_0 - \delta_f, x_0 + \delta_f\big)$, then $f(x) \in \big(f(x_0) - \epsilon, f(x_0) + \epsilon\big)$.

Choose $\delta = \delta_f$. As $g$ is increasing, we just need to show that $g(x_0 - \delta) > g(x_0) - \epsilon$ and $g(x_0 - \delta) < g(x_0) + \epsilon$.

Comment: So how about applying the definition of $g(x_0-\delta)$ and $g(x_0)-\epsilon$? Or assuming the inf is approached at a certain point...

Comment: I tried to do that... But I just found the wrong inequality

Comment: And you have a minor typo in your first setnence of your attempt, I think you meant $x_1 \leq x_2 \implies g(x_1)\leq g(x_2)$.  Perhaps that is why you also found the wrong inequality later.

Comment: Yes! I just edited that! Let me try again..

Comment: When you compare $g(x_0)$ and $g(x_0-\delta)$, one considers an additional interval of points  $(x_0-\delta, x_0]$ for the inf.  So how much better can we do by considering that interval?

Comment: $g(x_0 - \delta) = \inf \{ f(s) | x_0 - \delta < s \} \geq \inf \{f(s) - \epsilon | x_0 < s \} = g(x_0) - \epsilon$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32511/discussion-between-joan-and-michael).